# how to create and export to jar a library project that contains custom views

Tags: android, jar, custom-view, library-project

I have a some custom views that need to be reuse at diffrent projects,
So I created a new android project (which marked at properties as Library project)
and put at this project the code I want to reuse.
now I want to export it to jar, and use the jar file in other projects.
the problem is that none of the export options (only source code/ include resources..) not working: the jar file is being created, but when I'm using it - I'm getting compilation errors/ runtime exceptions (depands how I exported the jar..)

what am I'm doing wrong?
what is the right way to create jar file that provides additional custom views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need export to a jar file, you new android project just set the library to your `Library project`.

you can through this to set:

Right Click your project -- Properties -- android

in the right down area, you can set library project, just `add`

also, you can check this http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject

Comment: thanks very much. it worked :)        still seems to me that exporting to jar suppose to be possible, but for know I'll use this solution